# How to reuse a Jersy client to make various calls

Tags: jakarta-ee, jersey, jax-rs

I am new to Rest web services. I have created a Jersey Client and able to make a GET call. Now I am not able to understand that how I can make other POST call using the same client code. I need to change method post as well as the parameter for subsequent calls along with URI. Below are the question coming in my mind:

- Should I make a singleton class and get the Client Object and for every call I need to repeat the following lines.

WebResource webResource = client.resource("http://localhost:8080/get");

ClientResponse response = webResource.accept("application/json")
                   .get(ClientResponse.class);

- Is there any other way available that can improvise this approach.

Answer (score 0):

This is all about how you have designed your server implementation (I mean, identifying similarities between `GET` and `POST` call)

It is very simple, when you have identified the common code and created a function which will accepts the Http Method, EndPoint of your service and input.

So, beginning of your method, you will construct the complete endpoint of your webservice. Then, you need to check, if it is `GET` request, then append/construct the url for the same. Then, next you need to check, if it is `GET` or `POST` and accordingly, you need to initiate your request.

I just gave you an overview/code flow for your question. The actual implementation is upto you.

Comment: Thanks Ravi for your response. So you are saying that I need to construct my request dynamically by putting some checks for the method types, please correct me if I am able to get your point here.